# 5G PUSCH resource allocation at gNB for multiple UEs in Random Access procedure

Tags: network-access, 5g

As specified by 3gpp specifications, the initial access process is a random access procedure. The first step is to transmit a preamble over the PRACH occasion. If the base station successfully decodes the preamble, it will allocate the uplink PUSCH resource to the UE.

In the time domain, the PRACH occasion occurs periodically. My question is: suppose that **UE1** transmits its preamble over a PRACH occasion, and **UE2** transmits its preamble over the next PRACH occasion; if the based station has allocated the PUSCH resource to UE1 but has **no other PUSCH resources to UE2**, will the base station response Msg2 to UE2? Or what message will UE2 receive?